# How to get the statistics existing on a column, if any?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, statistics

I want to check in Transact SQL if a specific column in a table has statistics and if so to get them all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should do it.
I use it in a stored proc that browse the DB to find stats.
Works in SQL Server 2005 and probably older version as well.

```
SELECT S.NAME
FROM   SYS.OBJECTS AS O
       INNER JOIN SYS.STATS AS S
         ON O.OBJECT_ID = S.OBJECT_ID
       INNER JOIN SYS.STATS_COLUMNS AS SC
         ON SC.OBJECT_ID = S.OBJECT_ID
            AND S.STATS_ID = SC.STATS_ID
WHERE  (O.OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('MyTable','local'))
       AND (O.TYPE IN ('U'))
       AND (INDEXPROPERTY(S.OBJECT_ID,S.NAME,'IsStatistics') = 1)  /* only stats */
       AND (COL_NAME(SC.OBJECT_ID,SC.COLUMN_ID) = 'MyColumn')
```

Comment: Adding another where part "AND (S.USER_CREATED = 1)" is interesting in case you use this query to drop user-created queries, using this way: http://sqlsoundings.blogspot.be/2012/06/delete-statistics.html